# light a lit when I get an interrupt and keep it lit long enough to let me see it

Tags: microcontroller, led, circuit-design

I think that I am missing an interrupt from my radiochip but I'm not sure. I'm thinking about troubleshooting it by lighting up a led every time that the interruptline goes high. The problem is that the interrupt is handled so fast so that there is no chance that I can see if the LED gets lit, therefore I added a capacitor to the circuit but it does load fast enough to light the LED.

Do anyone have any suggestions on how I could build my troubleshoot circuit that lights upp the LED for enough time that I will have time to see it every time I get an interrupt?

---

Thank you all for the responces! it seems like a pulse stretcher is the way to go! I'll see if use the IC or build it myself. I found some easy sketch with 2 op-amps, resistors and capacitors.

Using a scope would of course be easier, but this has dual purpose for me, as much as I want to troubleshoot I also want to learn more about developing circuits.

Comment: I would attach my oscilloscope

Comment: You can also toggle the LED.  This is when you can control the interrupt.  A logic probe will also show very short pulses.

Comment: People are suggesting test equipment that I imagine you haven't got, as you asked how you could mod' your circuit to show the interrupt. Let us know if that's the case. Toggling the LED is an excellent suggestion (see above).

Comment: If you have some NOR or NAND gates to hand, you could make a nor/nand gate monostable circuit to stretch the pulses.

Comment: Punch "pulse stretcher" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: what is the foreground software doing in your MCU?  The interrupt could set a flag that the foreground sees, the forground could then turn on the led for some period of time such that you can see it.

Comment: if you have a uart, the interrupt routine could increment a counter variable the foreground task can see that counter change and print the value out the uart, if you see the counter changing there you go.

Comment: How often does your interrupt happen?  If it is too fast to see then toggling might not work, it might make the led "glow" or might be just too fast.  Can try two leds one on one off and toggle each, if it is too fast to see it toggle with your eyes if both are glowing then you can tell that it is toggling.  Or have the second one just be on, and you can tell from the brightness of the other if it is full on or dimmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for a monostable multivibrator configuration of 555 timer IC. You can easily set the LED on duration by varying R and C values. Connect interrupt pin to TRIG pin of 555 timer.
Example circuit [here](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/555-monostable-calculator):

[image]

Comment: I'm confused.  Why is this better than toggling it off and on with a single flip flop?  With the flip flop the LED will toggle on or off with each rising edge of the interrupt.

Comment: @Misunderstood The flip flop circuitry is simple to rig up and serves the purpose too.

Comment: 11 I was thinking maybe the OP did not realize the flip flop was the entire schematic.

Answer (score 0):

Right tools for the right job.  There's no substitute for a scope, preferentially with some advanced triggering options.

Another option would be to use your event to trigger a one-shot with a pulse width large enough to see.

Answer (score 0):

I you don't have a storage scope, and if the interrupt is not to frequent, add a flip flop and toggle the LED.

[image: flip flop]